# How to deploy non-ear website in jboss

Tags: jboss, jboss7.x, web-deployment, ear

I have a website comprising of a server and client. The server is an EAR, and I'm using JBoss to deploy it. The frontend is a series of html/js/css files that call into the backend via ajax.

I can deploy the frontend to an apache (2.2) server, and it works fine, however, I have a requirement that they both be on the same port (with different contexts).  How do I deploy my static files to jboss in their own context? It also needs to be able to use mod_rewrite (or something similar).

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could use Apache as the front end web server for the Jboss app server behind it.  You can deploy all your content to Jboss and configure Apache to manage it.

Or you can use Apache to serve the static content and still use it as the front end for Jboss, configuring Apache to map your Jboss port to Apache. You can configure it to use different contexts if you need to.

Take a look [here](http://www.jaysonjc.com/programming/configuring-apache-in-front-of-jboss-application-server-using-mod_jk.html)